# Domain name of a computer in multiple subnetwork

Tags: dns, domain

```
            +–––––––––––+        
    +–––––––+SOHO router|        
    |       +–––+–––––+–+        
+–––+––––+      |     |     +–––+
|Internet|      |     +–––––+PCs|
+–––+––––+      |           +–––+
    |       +–––+––+             
    +–––––––+Server|             
            +––––––+
```

I have this network setup. Both the server and the SOHO router have fix, distinct public ip addresses and public domain names (e.g.: server.com, soho.com) pointing to them.
My question is what private domain names should I use for the subnet behind the soho router to make the names consistent?
Should it look like xxxx.soho.com or it is not important because the subnet is behind a NAT?

Second question: The server has two NICs and the os (debian) asks for the name of the computer  and the domain during the installition.
Should I use (name=server, domain=com) or (name=something, domain=server.com)?
Can it have a public name and another name in the private subnet at the same time?

Comment: 1)it really doesn't matter that much, so long as you have appropriate DNS internally to resolve whatever you setup. 2)computers get one hostname. You can however point as many names to it using DNS as you'd like.